# React native styles management incorporating theme, global styles, component specific styles with props, inline styles i.e. one solution for all

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, themes, react-native-stylesheet

I am getting hard time in styles management in react native.

### BACKGROUND

Before using react navigation useTheme(), I had defined my color scheme and global styles like this

```
export const themeStyles = {
  primaryColor: 'blue',
  secondaryColor: 'grey'
}

export const Common = Stylesheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: themeStyles.secondaryColor
  }
})
```

Then I could easily access the colors and common/global styles anywhere like

```
<View style={Common.container}> </View>
<Text style={{color: themeStyles.primaryColor}> </Text>
```

I could easily define component specific styles too and use them

```
const CustomButton = ({ title, onPress}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} activeOpacity={0.5} style={styles.button}>
        <CustomText>{title} </CustomText>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles= Stylesheet.create({
  button: {
    color: "green",
    backgroundColor: themeStyles.secondaryColor
  },
});

export default CustomButton;
```

But if I'll be needing dynamic styles according to prop, I used to define it inline because I can't access props outside the component e.g

```
<CustomText style={{color: onPress? "blue": "grey"}}>{title} </CustomText>
```

Although I don't like inline styles, I want the flexibility though

### THE PROBLEM NOW

Then I used react navigation useTheme, But I am having hard time to get the flexibility I had. I used a hook to manage styles. Following is my code and I copied it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74866433/9399066)

```
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { useMemo } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

export default useThemedStyles = styles => props => {
  const theme = useTheme()

  return useMemo(() => {
    const css = typeof styles === 'function' ? styles(theme, props) : styles
    return StyleSheet.create(css)
  }, [props, theme])
}
```

Now using the hook:

```
const CustomButton = ({ title, onPress}) => {
  const styles = useStyles();
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}> 
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} activeOpacity={0.5} style={styles.button}>
        <CustomText>{title} </CustomText>
      </LinearGradient>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
  );
};

const useStyles = useThemedStyles((theme, props) => ({
      button: {
        color: "green",
        backgroundColor: theme.secondaryColor
      },
    container: theme.container

}));
```

Notice **container: theme.container**. I have to redefine the global/common styles in component specific styles to use them, I can't directly access the theme variables in the JSX and so on. I have to use useStyles() at the start of each component (previously I just imported the file and can use in anywhere, no extra code). The only good thing is that I can now pass props to the useStyles() to avoid inlinestyles

**So, How to get all the flexibility back with minimal changes?
How to use common styles and colors without redefining them in the component specific styles?
How to avoid declaring useStyles() in every component?
How to pass props to component stylesheet (which is outside the component) effectively?**

Comment: Can't you use Styled Component?

Comment: @HardikChavda sorry didn't get it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Using styled components you can create global styled component for i.e. Container and styled components also provide easier way to access props so you can pass props and use for more understanding please read [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-styled-components-with-react-native/)